# printing (save as pdf) issues in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, pdf, printing

The problem is this - in Chrome, this page is saved as PDF correctly on one computer, and have issues on another.
I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
.fullscreen
{
    width:1156px;
    height:893px;
    float:left;
    background:url(2.jpg) no-repeat;
}
.firstpage{background:url(1.jpg) no-repeat;}
.lastpage{background:url(3.jpg) no-repeat;}
@media print {
  body {
    width:1156;
    height:893;
  }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="fullscreen firstpage"></div>
<div class="fullscreen"></div>
<div class="fullscreen lastpage"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's just 3 div's with 3 different background images (same size - 1156x893). On my home computer, everything is ok. There's no difference if I place @page{size:1156 893;} or size:auto, or (as in this case) I don't place it at all.

The problem is on my office computer, where no matter what I do, the size of the page in printing mode is always 1286x909, and the content is zoomed and goes out of the page. Am I missing something here or the problem is not in the page code at all? And if it's not in the code, where do I have to change something to make it right? If necessary, I can provide the 2 PDF files as well.

I'm using Windows 7 with last version of Chrome on both computers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a full css style for printing.

The code you wrote for printing is just for the body.

```
@media print {
  body {
    width:1156;
    height:893;
  }
}
```

Due to the absence of that css style, the browser is taking default values for the pdf. So it would be better if you create a whole css style for 
You can check at this post to know how to do that.
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Please, let me know if that worked out for you :)